# AutoSuggestBox.focus doesn't work first time

Tags: c#, user-interface, uwp, focus, autosuggest

An simple thing, a button that when you click it opens an autosuggestbox and lets me focus on it and open the keyboard on mobile or simply be able to write without click by myself on the "zone of text"

```
Boolean AutoSuggestBoxRicercaOn = true;

public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    AutoSuggestion.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
}

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (AutoSuggestBoxRicercaOn)
    {
        AutoSuggestion.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        AutoSuggestBoxRicercaOn = false;

        AutoSuggestion.Focus(FocusState.Programmatic);
    }
    else
    {
        AutoSuggestion.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        AutoSuggestBoxRicercaOn = true;
    }
}
```

[the xml is an autosuggestbox and a buttton]

It works from the second time when I click on button to make the ASbox visible, not the first - why? How can I force it to be able to do that on the first time too ?

Thanks to all :}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It works from the second time when I click on button to make the ASbox visible, not the first - why?

If you're trying to get the return result of setting focus method, you will find that the first time `AutoSuggestion.Focus` returns `false`, which means for some reasons the control is not focusable (see `Focus` method of [`Control`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.control#Focus) class). This should be the reason that the first time the `AutoSuggestBox` doesn't get focused.

For why the control is not focusable, it may be caused by the `AutoSuggestBox` is not completed initialized since I add a little `Task.Delay`, the first time worked. Test code snippet as follow:

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (AutoSuggestBoxRicercaOn)
    {
        AutoSuggestion.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        AutoSuggestBoxRicercaOn = false;
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.05));
        bool setresult = AutoSuggestion.Focus(FocusState.Programmatic);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("the setting focus result:" + setresult)
    }
    else
    {
        AutoSuggestion.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        AutoSuggestBoxRicercaOn = true;
    }
}
```

> How can I force it to be able to do that on the first time too ?

You could put the initial `Visibility` property setting inside `Page_Loaded` event handle instead of the constructor. Which can take the same effects and the first time can work.

```
<Page
    ...
    mc:Ignorable="d" 
    Loaded="Page_Loaded">

private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    AutoSuggestion.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```